# React Router blank page on refresh. Page has props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a react router for if the user is authenticated.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={GuitarTable} />
    <Route path="/guitar/:id" component={GuitarDetails} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I have a link on an authenticated page that looks like this:

```
<Link to={`/guitar/${guitar._id}`}>Details</Link>
```

When the user goes to /guitar/:id from their history a page is rendered blank, the navigation doesn't even show up. I am assuming that the props were not passed in thus the page won't render properly. However I don't want the user to have to go back to the dashboard every time.

I want to set up the /guitar/:id page in a way even if no props are passed, it checks that the user authenticated and then react takes the :id param from the URL and makes a network call to get the information from the database.

How can I stop this from rendering a blank page and render the page properly upon refresh?